# Rail создание связанных моделей

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть пользователь, который может создавать задачи и проекты. Задачи могут быть как самостоятельной единицей, так и принадлежать к проекту. Следовательно, необходимо иметь возможность создавать задачи на странице уже существующего проекта.

### Модели

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :projects
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RankedModel
  ranks :row_order

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, allow_destroy: true
end
```

#### Контроллер Project

```
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.tasks.build
  end

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

....

private
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

#### Контроллер Task

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    request.referrer
  end

  def index
    @tasks = current_user.tasks.rank(:row_order).all
    @task = current_user.tasks.new
    @projects = current_user.projects.all
    @project = current_user.projects.new
  end

  def update_row_order
    @task = Task.find(task_params[:task_id])
    @task.row_order_position = task_params[:row_order_position]
    @task.save

    render nothing: true
  end

  def create

    @task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

......

private
  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:task_id, :name, :row_order_position)
  end
```

#### Для страницы существующего проекта сделал следующее `view`:

url: /projects/1

```
  <table>
    <% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= task.name %></td>

        </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>


<%=form_for([@project, @project.tasks.build]) do |f| %>

      <div class="input-group">

        <div aria-describedby="add_task">
          <%=f .text_field :name, class: 'form-control ' %>
        </div>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <%= f.submit 'Добавить', class: 'btn btn-success btn-secondary', id: "add_task" %>
               </span>
      </div>

      <% end %>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать `task` связанный с конкретным `project` через метод `show`?

## И в дополнение поля из db:

```
create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "status"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "row_order"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "project_id"
  end
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста правильно я сделал ассоциации? И как в контролере в контроллере создавать task что бы она принадлежала определенному проекту и была видна только авторизованному пользователю - `@tasks = current_user.projects.tasks.new`?

Comment: Отредактировал и обновил вопрос. Пожалуйста подскажите в каком направлении искать ошибку - не понимаю где может быть проблема, в контроллере или я просто что то не так делаю во `view `

Comment: `show` в контроллере выглядит крайне подозрительно.

Comment: Согласен( Попытаюсь объяснить что я хотел сделать. Есть пользователь - у пользователя есть возможность создавать проекты - зайдя в конкретный проект - пользователь должен иметь возможность создавать там задачи, которые будут привязаны к этому проекту

Comment: Я б в вашей ситуации вооружался [**ломиком**](http://pryrepl.org/) и вскрыл то место, в котором это имя выводится с целью посмотреть, что в `task`. Предлагаю с этого и начать :)

Comment: А `show` выглядит подозрительно, потому что вы записываете и перезаписываете в `@task`, ещё и значения разных типов.

Comment: пожалуйста подскажите, что подразумевается под  `"потому что вы записываете и перезаписываете в @task, ещё и значения разных типов"`? не совсем понял(

Comment: `@task = одно` и сразу `@task = другое`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35916/discussion-between-d-side-and-alexandr-dmitrenko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `projects#show` тут совершенно не важен, на самом деле. Форму, в теории, можно вывести где угодно, был бы проект.

Важно подготовить другое: точку назначения для данных из формы.

> Представление -› **маршрут** -› **контроллер** -› модель.

#### Маршрут

Rails сильно поощряет использование в маршрутах **ресурсов**. Если `resources :projects` там уже есть, то маршрут создания новых задач можно добавить следующим образом:

```rb
resources :projects do # Это уже должно быть
  resources :tasks, only: [:create]
end
```

Получится `POST /projects/:project_id/tasks`.

#### Контроллер

Типичный паттерн "ресурса внутри скоупа": с помощью `before_action` контроллер получает "место действия" (в данном случае задачи отдельного проекта), а затем пробует в этом "месте действия" совершить то, что сказано:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action do
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

  def create
    @project.tasks.create(project_params)
  end

  def project_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:не, :знаю, :что, :тут, :у, :вас)
  end
end
```

Три однострочника. Примерно к такой простоте контроллеров в Rails и стремятся, поэтому и не боятся при случае сделать отдельный, даже если в нём нужен всего один метод.

Comment: Обновил данные по своим контроллерам и `view `. При вставке указанного вами кода

`before_action do
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end`

Возникает ошибка: [скриншот](http://joxi.ru/eAO7KpbF474OwA)

Comment: @AlexandrDmitrenko если у вас в контроллере есть что-то ещё, вам придётся вышеуказанный код адаптировать. Я не могу отвечать за любые изменения, накладываемые конкретным проектом. В этом случае, скорее всего, будет достаточно указать `before_action`'у конкретные экшены, но у вас в этом контроллере слишком много свалено.